# WhiteSpace issue, when using handlebars with <input> tag

Tags: javascript, html, forms, handlebars.js

I am setting a default value inside an input using handlebars it Looks like this.

```
        <div class="form-group" id="eventDead">
            <label for="eventDead">Event Deadline</label>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="eventDead" id="eventDead" value={{this.eventDeadline}} readonly/>
        </div>
```

The problem is that if the value eventDeadline="I want to host something",

the output on the page is "I", Only the first word before the whitespace is added. 
How can fix this?

Demo below:

```js
var source   = document.getElementById("entry-template").innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var context = {eventDeadline: "You want to host something"}
var html = template(context)
$("#value").html(html)
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.12/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            <div class="form-group" id="eventDead">
                <label for="eventDead">Event Deadline</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="eventDead" id="eventDead" value={{this.eventDeadline}} readonly/>
            </div>
</script>
<div id="value"></div>
```

Comment: Can you please create demo of it?

Comment: try wrapping the `{{this.eventDeadline}}` in double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code. change your input value tag like this

```
value="{{this.eventDeadline}}"
```

```js
var source   = document.getElementById("entry-template").innerHTML;
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
var context = {eventDeadline: "You want to host something"}
var html = template(context)
$("#value").html(html)
```

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.12/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
            <div class="form-group" id="eventDead">
                <label for="eventDead">Event Deadline</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="eventDead" id="eventDead"  value="{{this.eventDeadline}}" readonly/>
            </div>
</script>
<div id="value"></div>
```